# How can I embed unicode string constants in a source file?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, string, unicode, constants

I'm writing some unit tests which are going to verify our handling of various resources that use other character sets apart from the normal latin alphabet: Cyrilic, Hebrew etc.

The problem I have is that I cannot find a way to embed the expectations in the test source file:  here's an example of what I'm trying to do...

```
///
/// Protected: TestGetHebrewConfigString
///  
void CPrIniFileReaderTest::TestGetHebrewConfigString()
{
    prwstring strHebrewTestFilePath = GetTestFilePath( strHebrewTestFileName );
    CPrIniFileReader prIniListReader( strHebrewTestFilePath.c_str() );
    prIniListReader.SetCurrentSection( strHebrewSubSection );   

    CPPUNIT_ASSERT( prIniListReader.GetConfigString( L"דונדארןמע" ) == L"דונהשךוק") );
}
```

This quite simply doesnt work.  Previously I worked around this using a macro which calls a routine to transform a narrow string to a wide string (we use towstring all over the place in our applications so it's existing code)

```
#define UNICODE_CONSTANT( CONSTANT ) towstring( CONSTANT )

wstring towstring( LPCSTR lpszValue )
{
    wostringstream os;
    os << lpszValue;
    return os.str();
}
```

The assertion in the test above then became:

```
CPPUNIT_ASSERT( prIniListReader.GetConfigString( UNICODE_CONSTANT( "דונדארןמע" ) ) == UNICODE_CONSTANT( "דונהשךוק" ) );
```

This worked OK on OS X but now I'm porting to linux and I'm finding that the tests are all failing: it all feels rather hackish as well.   Can anyone tell me if they have a nicer solution to this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A tedious but portable way is to build your strings using numeric escape codes. For example:

```
wchar_t *string = L"דונדארןמע";
```

becomes:

```
wchar_t *string = "\x05d3\x05d5\x05e0\x05d3\x05d0\x05e8\x05df\x05de\x05e2";
```

You have to convert all your Unicode characters to numeric escapes. That way your source code becomes encoding-independent.

You can use online tools for conversion, such as [this one](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/). It outputs the JavaScript escape format `\uXXXX`, so just search & replace `\u` with `\x` to get the C format.

Comment: In windows wchar_t is 16bits and everyone else is 32bits.  Does this effect what hex literals need to be listed?  Or does `\x05d3` work equally well for 16 and 32 bit?

Comment: There is no limit on the number of hex digits after \x, so this should work the same whatever sizeof(wchar_t). See this topic for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735101/unicode-escaping-in-c-c

Answer (score 11):

You have to tell GCC which encoding your file uses to code those characters into the file.

Use the option `-finput-charset=charset`, for example `-finput-charset=UTF-8`. Then you need to tell it about the encoding used for those string literals at runtime. That will determine the values of the wchar_t items in the strings. You set that encoding using `-fwide-exec-charset=charset`, for example `-fwide-exec-charset=UTF-32`. Beware that the size of the encoding (utf-32 needs 32bits, utf-16 needs 16bits) must not exceed the size of `wchar_t` gcc uses.

You can adjust that. That option is mainly useful for compiling programs for `wine`, designed to be compatible with windows. The option is called `-fshort-wchar`, and will most likely then be 16bits instead of 32bits, which is its usual width for gcc on linux.

Those options are described in more detail in `man gcc`, the gcc manpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define UNICODE_CONSTANT( CONSTANT ) towstring( CONSTANT )

wstring towstring( LPCSTR lpszValue ) {
    wostringstream os;
    os << lpszValue;
    return os.str(); 
}
```

This does not actually convert at all between Unicode encodings, which requires a dedicated routine. You need to keep your source code and data encodings unified- most people use UTF-8- and then convert that to the OS-specific encoding if necessary (such as UTF-16 on Winders).