# Unexpected output of std::wcout << L"élève"; in Windows Shell

Tags: c++, unicode, wchar-t, mojibake

While testing some functions to convert strings between wchar_t and utf8 I met the following weird result with Visual C++ express 2008

```
std::wcout << L"élève" << std::endl;
```

prints out "ÚlÞve:" which is obviously not what is expected.

This is obviously a bug. How can that be ? How am I suppose to deal with such "feature" ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C++ compiler does not support Unicode in code files. You have to replace those characters with their escaped versions instead.

Try this:

```
std::wcout << L"\x00E9l\x00E8ve" << std::endl;
```

Also, your console must support Unicode as well.

UPDATE:

It's not going to produce the desired output in your console, because the console does not support Unicode.

Comment: Unfortunately, using Dave's code yields exactly the same output. 
So I guess it means that the shell doesn't support unicode.

Comment: It seems I should be able to activate UTF-8 support in the shell by issuing the command chcp 65001. How can I do this from within a program before writing out things ?

Comment: It's not going to output the full UTF-16. You're lucky if you get ANSI output, because the high order bytes are knocked off. But the characters are ANSI page 1252 compatible.

Answer (score 2):

I found these related questions with useful answers
[Is there a Windows command shell that will display Unicode characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379240/is-there-a-windows-command-shell-that-will-display-unicode-characters)
[How can I embed unicode string constants in a source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442735/how-can-i-embed-unicode-string-constants-in-a-source-file)

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442735/how-can-i-embed-unicode-string-constants-in-a-source-file).  It shows how you can actually hard-code unicode characters into files using some compilers (I'm not sure what the options would be got MSVC).

Answer (score 1):

> This is obviously a bug. How can that be?

While other operating systems have dispensed with legacy character encodings and switched to UTF-8, Windows uses **two** legacy encodings: An "OEM" code page (used at the command prompt) and an "ANSI" code page (used by the GUI).

Your C++ source file is in ANSI code page 1252 (or possibly 1254, 1256, or 1258), but your console is interpreting it as OEM code page 850.

Answer (score 0):

You IDE and the compiler use the ANSI code page.
The console uses the OEM code page.

It also matter what are you doing with those conversion functions.