# number of digits in a hex escape code in C/C++

Tags: c++, unicode, escaping

I'm having a dispute with a colleague of mine. She says that the following:

```
char* a = "\x000aaxz";
```

will/can be seen by the compiler as "\x000aa". I do not agree with her, as I think you can have a maximum number of 4 hex characters after the `\x`. Can you have more than 4 hex chars?

Who is right here?

Comment: Info on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx there they are very clear about `\x05five` case

Answer (score 30, accepted):

§2.13.2/4:

> The escape \xhhh consists of the
>   backslash followed by x followed by
>   one or more hexadecimal digits that
>   are taken to specify the value of the
>   desired character. There is no limit
>   to the number of digits in a
>   hexadecimal sequence. A sequence of
>   octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by the first character that is
>   not an octal digit or a hexadecimal
>   digit, respectively.

She is right.

However, you can terminate it early by eager catenation: the sequence of literals `"\x000a" "axz"` specifies a single four-character string literal. (2.13.4/3)

Also note that Unicode [uses 21-bit code points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Architecture_and_terminology); it doesn't stop at 16 bits.

Comment: I've gotten bitten by the unlimited hex literals on several occasions when the character after the escape sequence just happened to be a valid hex digit.

Comment: In Visual C++, wchar_t is 16-bit. On Linux, it's 32-bit.

Comment: is "eager catenation" the only valid way to end hex escape sequence?

Comment: @sukhmel You can specify the next character using a universal character name, which is a hex Unicode codepoint: `"\x000a\u0061xz"`. This is quite inferior to catenation. I don't think there's any other way.

Comment: Thank you, I also found advice of using `" \b"` as stopper. Both this and codepoint seems to be less convenient than catenation.

Comment: @sukhmel `" \b"` will only be printed the same by a terminal with support for the backspace character. That implies that it's really text output, and you seldom use a hex escape in text anyway. Use a `\u` codepoint rather than `\x` in text. `\u` requires exactly 4 hex digits and `\U` exactly 8. They don't have the issue with termination. (But, the codepoint can only be translated to the character in the selected runtime character set, whereas `\x` lets you do the encoding.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: My preference is often to break out escapes into their own separately-quoted sections: `"The item cost " "\x123" "12.34"`.  It's a little bulky, but it makes the boundaries of the escaped items clear.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from MSDN on C++ character constants:

> Octal escape sequences, specified in the form \ooo, consist of a backslash and one, two, or three octal characters. Hexadecimal escape sequences, specified in the form \xhhh, consist of the characters \x followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits. Unlike octal escape constants, there is no limit on the number of hexadecimal digits in an escape sequence.

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

well, for that matter, hex escape sequence ends at a non hex character,
e.g \x0abc9k is 0abc9 in hex and then 'k'
so in order to end a hex sequence, you will have to use double quotes twice at the end of it
e.g. \x0ab""c9k , which takes only 0ab as hex

or alternately you could use octal escape sequence as there is limit to the numbers in octal escape sequence so there be maximum only three octal digits in it..
e.g. \o1234 is 123 in octal and then '4'

So, yes, she is right.