# Create string with ESC command using HEX definition

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to create string with special characer defined in HEX format:

```
std::string s = "\xFEd" ; 
error C2022: '65242' : too big for character
```

In case `std::string s = "\xFE d" ;`  everything goes fine. How to tell string constructor treat "d" as string "d" and not numeric definition character in first case?

Comment: "d" is taken as a part of hexcode? then `"\x00FEd"` should work. If not, then `"\xFE" + "d"` must work.

Comment: I agree. 'd' should not be interpreted as part of the hex code. What compiler are you using?

Comment: You could do e.g. `"\xfe""d"`

Comment: in case '\x00FEd' have error ''65242' : too big for character'

Comment: Similar question, but not really a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735101/number-of-digits-in-a-hex-escape-code-in-c-c

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in tags "visual C++" so I assume Microsoft compiler from Visual Studio.

Please review the reference and examples [at this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6aw8xdf2.aspx). It tells what you should use, but it seems .. a little buggy. For example:

```
octal              \ooo
hexadecimal        \xhhh     <- note the 3 Hs
Unicode (UTF-8)    \uxxxx
Unicode (UTF-16)   \Uxxxxxxxx
```

and few pagedowns later, examples:

> **A hexadecimal escape sequence is a backslash followed by the character x, followed by a sequence of hexadecimal digits.** An escape sequence that contains no hexadecimal digits causes compiler error C2153: "hex constants must have at least one hex digit". An escape sequence that has hexadecimal and non-hexadecimal characters is evaluated as the last non-hexadecimal character. **The highest hexadecimal value is 0xff**.

```
char c1 = '\x0050';  // char 'P'    <-- note 4 digits as 1 char
char c2 = '\x0pqr';  // char 'r'
```

Note the `\x0pqr` thing. Fun! I'd suspect compilation error, but no!

(..)

I've just found exact answer on MSDN: [short info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edsza5ck.aspx) and [long info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx). Exerpt from the latter:

> Using embedded hexadecimal escape codes to specify string constants can cause unexpected results. The following example seeks to create a string literal that contains the ASCII 5 character, followed by the characters f, i, v, and e:

```
"\x05five"
```

> The actual result is a hexadecimal 5F, which is the ASCII code for an underscore, followed by the characters i, v, and e. To get the correct result, you can use one of these:

```
"\005five"     // Use octal constant.  
"\x05" "five"  // Use string splicing.
```