# Polish characters in QT app

Tags: c++, qt

I' ve got a problem with my app.
i'm beginner in Qt so I tried to make a cryptograph.
Everything works fine but there is a problem with all polish characters (ó,ę,ź,ż,ą). I mean that there are squares visible not a text (QplainText).

UPDATED: problem was connected with propriate encoding, .toLatin method sometimes do not supports national characters, to provide your app having ó,ę etc.
You have to change method from latin to unicode or encode on your own .
This post is for all people who have problem with it. Sadly all qt forums say only about the latin method
which was not good in my case

Comment: What do you mean there are squares? In the qt creator or a qtextedit? Normally, squares means the text renderer could not find appropriate font to reder the text. Maybe you system have no polish font installed or the polish character is not intepreted as polish character but assome unrecognized characters.

Comment: I'm on linux so it shouln't be way that some characters are unrecognized, but it seems like it. I 've got QlineEdit where i type a text and when i click on button the converted text is shown on QPlaintextedit and there are these squares.

Comment: On any os, if there is no font to render a character, the character is unrecognizable(which could be sqaures). And you need provide a simplest testable example for your problem.

Comment: So what is a solution ?

Comment: **provide a simplest testable example for your problem**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I find a solution ! :)

Before my code looks like it

```
QString Encrypted;
for(int i = 0 ; i < Text.length() ;i++)
{

  Encrypted[i] = Text[--n].toLatin()-b; // where b is random int


}
```

I changed method from .toLatin to .unicode and all works fine ; )

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the encoding of your code files to unicode.

see [How can I embed unicode string constants in a source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442735/how-can-i-embed-unicode-string-constants-in-a-source-file)